# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined as in c#

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Can someone please look at the code below and tell me what I am doing wrong here. I am just trying to return a value based on some conditions but getting an error saying

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined as theer is no implicit conversion between int and null..
```

but my return type is a nullable int so shouldn't it allow both null and an int value.

```
public static Expression<Func<BidCountry, int?>> GetETimeData =>
       !bidcountry.EeTimeOptionID.HasValue ? null : bidcountry.EeTimeOptionID.Value == 31 ?
        2 : bidcountry.EeTimeOptionID.Value == 32 ? 4 :
        bidcountry.EeTimeOptionID.Value == 33 ? 8 :
        bidcountry.EeTimeOptionID.Value == 34 ? 16 :
        bidcountry.EeTimeOptionID.Value == 35 ? 32 : null;
```

Comment: that piece of code is horrible and extremely hard to read. I would consider using a switch.

Comment: @SelmanGenç Since they want an Expression they might want it to be convertible to SQL and a switch statement wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: Cast your `null` at the end of that horribly complex expression so that it has a type of `Nullable<int>`: `complexExpression == 35 ? 32 : (int?) null;`.  Otherwise, the null isn't a nullable int, it's just null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone..Can you tell me how I can make it better please.

Comment: If its not being used for SQL you could probably leverage the fact that the result is Math.Pow(2,Value-30) IIF HasValue && 30 < Value < 36 otherwise, null

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it being used for sql generation.